# Difference between bulk exceptions and normal exceptions in oracle.please explain with example?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Please explain difference bulk exception and normal exception. Which conditions use bulk exception?

Answer (score 1):

Bulk exceptions are exceptions that have be captured by a `BULK COLLECT` statement in PL/SQL.  There is no fundamental difference between bulk exceptions and normal ones, and now fundamental difference with where ... or how ... they are thrown.  This is really about how the exceptions are handled.

BULK COLLECT allows you to collect multiple exceptions rather than terminating an operation on the first exception.

Reference:

- http://www.databasejournal.com/features/oracle/bulk-exceptions-in-oracle.html